# Error while building lcms2.5 on MinGW & MSYS

Tags: mingw, msys

I downloaded lcms2-2.5 and configured using sh configure --build=mingw32 on MinGW-MSYS2.After running make I am getting the following error:

Compilation Step:

```
E:/software/utils/bin/sh.exe ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"lcms2\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"lcms2\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.5\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"lcms2\ 2.5\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHasJPEG=1 -DHasZLIB=1 -I. -I../include -I../include    -g -O2 -MT cmscnvrt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/cmscnvrt.Tpo -c -o cmscnvrt.lo cmscnvrt.c
Xcmscnvrt.Tpo -c -o cmscnvrt.lo cmscnvrt.lo
```

Error:

```
libtool: compile: warning: libobj name `cmscnvrt.Tpo -c -o cmscnvrt.lo cmscnvrt.
lo' may not contain shell special characters.
rm: unknown option -- c
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 "-DPACKAGE_NAME=\\lcms2\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"
lcms2\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.5\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\\lcms2 2.5\"" "-DPACKAGE_BUG
REPORT=\\\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_
STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=
1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"
 -DHasJPEG=1 -DHasZLIB=1 -I. -I../include -I../include -g -O2 -MT cmscnvrt.lo -M
D -MP -MF .deps/cmscnvrt.Tpo -c -o cmscnvrt.lo cmscnvrt.c"  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -
o .libs/cmscnvrt.Tpo -c -o cmscnvrt.lo cmscnvrt.o
gcc.exe: error: cmscnvrt.o: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'cmscnvrt.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [cmscnvrt.lo] Error 1
```

Kindly help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've come across this error compiling PROJ.4. Google search brought me here.